# My IbOutlet from my TableViewCell custom class is never being initialized

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

I have this issue. I'm not able to access my outlet from anywhere, because if I don't wrap it as optional the app crashes saying always "found unexpected nil..."
If I unwrap it It doesn't crash but never gets initialized.
My awake from nib method is never called from the custom class `shopsTableViewCell : UITableViewCell`
I've been stackoverflowing and read if you pretend to load your custom cell from storyboard you have to comment this line, otherwise it will overwrite the current instance, so I've commented this line:

```
tableView.registerClass(shopsTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

But now I get this **error:**

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   NSInternalInconsistencyException, reason: unable to dequeue a cell
>   with identifier cell - must register a nib or a class for the
>   identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard

In storyboard I've checked and the file's owner it's okay since its linking to the custom class, and the outlets are also well done.

This is my `ViewController` class code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit


class showShopsTableView : ViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating {
    var selectedRow : shopsTableViewCell!
var index : Int = 0
@IBOutlet var searchBar: UISearchBar!

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!


let resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController:nil)

var searchActive : Bool = false
var filtered:[String] = []


override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    //Configure TableView
    addTableViewToView()

    //Clean array data
    TableData.removeAll()

    //Retrieve data asynchronously
    let call = webApi()
    call.retrieveAllShops(self.tableView)




}

private func addTableViewToView(){

    tableView = UITableView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds, style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    searchBar.delegate = self
    tableView.registerClass(shopsTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    resultSearchController.searchBar.delegate = self

    resultSearchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["Filter", "Map"]


    tableView.tableHeaderView = resultSearchController.searchBar


    self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)
}



override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    if let rect = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame {
        let y = rect.size.height + rect.origin.y
        self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake( y, 0, 0, 0)
    }
}

//Segue Method
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! detailViewShop
    destinationViewController.dataSend = self.selectedRow

    destinationViewController.titleText = self.selectedRow.shopTitle // set your properties here
    destinationViewController.descriptionText = self.selectedRow.shopDesc

    destinationViewController.imageOutlet = self.selectedRow.shopImageTitle

    destinationViewController.shopCategory = self.selectedRow.shopCategory

    destinationViewController.brands = self.selectedRow.Brands

}


//TableView Delegate Methods
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    selectedRow = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as! shopsTableViewCell

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("cell", sender: self)
}


func tableView(tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int
{
    if(searchActive) {
        return filtered.count
    }
    return TableData.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell : shopsTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! shopsTableViewCell
    if(searchActive){
        cell.textLabel?.text = filtered[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = TableData[indexPath.row]
    }


    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    let image : UIImage = UIImage(named: "versace_shop.jpg")!
    cell.imageView?.image = image

    cell.shopImg = UIImageView.init(image: UIImage.init(named:"versace_shop.jpg"))
    let arrayIndex : String = "\(self.index)"
    let data = nsDict.objectForKey(arrayIndex)
    print(data)
    //Title
    cell.shopTitle = data?.objectForKey("name") as? String
    cell.shopName?.text = "alfredo"
    //Description
    cell.shopDesc = data?.objectForKey("name") as? String
    //Description
    cell.shopCategory = data?.objectForKey("Type") as? String
    //Brands
    cell.Brands = data?.objectForKey("Brands") as? String



    self.index += 1
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}
//SearchBar Delegate Methods
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = true;
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
}

func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    filtered = TableData.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
        let tmp: NSString = text
        let range = tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
        return range.location != NSNotFound
    })
    if(filtered.count == 0){
        searchActive = false;
    } else {
        searchActive = true;
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

}

func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
    filterContentForSearchText(searchBar.text!, scope: searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![selectedScope])
}
func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
    tableView.reloadData()
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

And this is my custom tableViewCell class code::

```
import Foundation

import UIKit

class shopsTableViewCell : UITableViewCell{

    @IBOutlet weak var shopName: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var shopImg: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var shopDescription: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!

    var shopTitle : String?
    var shopDesc : String?
    var shopImageTitle : String?
    var shopCategory : String?
    var Brands : String?


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }


    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    }
}
```

Edited to show prototypes:
[image]
[image]

[image]

edit to add outlets image :

[image]

this is the code for the `retrieveAllShopsMethod`:

```
    func retrieveAllShops(tableView : UITableView){
        setGetShopsListUrl()

        call(tableView)
    }

    private func setGetShopsListUrl(){
        userApiCallUrl += "shops/all"
    }

private func call(tableView : UITableView){
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: userApiCallUrl)!)

        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        request.HTTPBody = postParam.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
            guard error == nil && data != nil else {
                // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }
            if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
                // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            }


            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

            let json: AnyObject? = responseString!.parseJSONString

            self.parseJson((json as! NSMutableArray), tableView: tableView)

        }

        task.resume()
    }

    private func parseJson(json : NSMutableArray, tableView : UITableView){

        var c : Int = 0
        for j in json {

            //Create main value
            guard let value = j.valueForKey("value")?.valueForKey("value")! else{
                continue
            }

            //Get name
            guard let Name : String = (value.valueForKey("Name")?.valueForKey("en") as? String) else {
                continue
            }
         TableData.append(Name)
        }

        doTableRefresh(tableView);
    }
```

TableData is a global var:

```
var TableData:Array< String > = Array < String >()
```

Comment: Is shopsTableViewCell is your prototype cell of UITableView in storyboard?

Comment: you are not suppose to call `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` on your own. UIKit will do it once it is ready to do so. same for all `viewDid...` and `viewWill...` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are setting up the tableView in storyboard, but then also have code to set it up in the viewController, probably causing issues.  If things are wired in storyboard correctly, you can remove:

From `addTableViewToView()`, remove the following lines, since they are already (or can be) set in the storyboard:

```
tableView = UITableView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds, style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.registerClass(shopsTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

Also, can you show the outlets on the tableView from the storyboard?  You may have unnecessary outlets there too.

**TIPS**

Just some friendly feedback on the code:

- class names should begin with a capital letter.
- constants/variables should begin with a lowercase letter.
- you have a segue and cell with the identifier `cell`.  Should be unique and descriptive.
- UIKit includes Foundation.  No need to import both (although it's not hurting anything).

These tips/best practices will help others examine your code more easily.

Comment: I've commented the lines you said, and the tableView is loading empty, without results. I have to investigate a bit more why, but maybe your answer is already the good one. Also, would like to thank you for the friendly feedback, it really helps and I appreciate a lot. I've edited my post to show the outlets

Comment: Also need to remove `self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)` I don't see where tableData is being initialized or assigned values except in `searchBar()`.  Does it have any values?

Comment: in viewDidLoad() ->  call.retrieveAllShops(self.tableView)
It is an async call that load data into an array and in tableView, sent as a param. Going to edit to add this code.

Answer (score 1):

select the prototype cell, go to

`attributes inspector -> table view cell -> identifier` and make sure you called it `cell`

Comment: There is already an image in my post illustrating this step, and is well done.Edit: my mistake, I thought this step was illustrated with an image but it wasn't so I've editted to add this image. It wasn't the solution but thanks for your comment.

Comment: The image in your post doesn't show that you have named the identifier `cell`

Comment: did you connect the tableview delegate and source to the view controller on storyboard?